# how to maintain image resolution after doing zooming?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

after doing zooming i am loosing image resolution.

How to maintained the resolution of an image. even the image is zoom - in.

@thanks in adavance.

I try my level best no luck.

Is core graphics will help me out. or CATiledLayer will help me out with this kind of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a large initial image, which is scaled down by the app at run time.  If your screen is 768 x 1024, then the image placed in the zoomable view might be 1536 x 2048.  This way it maintains detail even as you zoom.

If you need an even larger image, there are some 3rd party libraries on GitHub that support dividing up larger images and placing them in a scroll view.

Comment: Hi Javy Can i get that link. from GitHub.

Comment: Here's one: https://github.com/psineur/Tile-Cutter/tree/aa2efb73f04ff1dbe1821ae6f5e1f2b22d9e6b85